# Get rid of a white frame in GWT popup panel

Tags: html, css, gwt

I'm creating a popup panel in GWT to display a loading CSS animation while a RPC operation is running. To do this, I've created a popup panel using a uiBinder element. Thus, everything is working fine, but I don't know how to get rid of a white frame that "surrounds" my popup panel. Let me show you this:

[image]

What I want to achieve this:

[image]

Ok, let me show you the code from my popup panel...

```
public class LoadingDialogMessage extends PopupPanel {

private static LoadingDialogMessageUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(LoadingDialogMessageUiBinder.class);

interface LoadingDialogMessageUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, LoadingDialogMessage> {}

public LoadingDialogMessage() {
    setWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    setAutoHideEnabled(true);
    setGlassEnabled(true);
    center();
}
}
```

Here is the code from my ui.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
 <g:HTMLPanel styleName="loading_container">
    <label class="loading_label">Loading info from itsaseus buoys</label>
    <div class="bubblingG">
        <span id="bubblingG_1">
        </span>
        <span id="bubblingG_2">
        </span>
        <span id="bubblingG_3">
        </span>
    </div>
</g:HTMLPanel> 
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The CSS associated:

```
.loading_label{
color:#ffffff; 
font-size: 85%; 
text-align: center; 
text-decoration: none; 
/*  font-stretch: condensed;  */
font-weight: bold; 
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.loading_container{
height: 100%;
background: #3a9bff;
    padding: 0.5em; 
text-align: center;
border:3px solid;
border-color: #4452ED;
/* border-radius */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
/* box-shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;    
}
```

The rest of CSS are automatically generated for the loading animation from this [page](http://cssload.net/). I don't think they have nothing to do with it because if I remove the divs that use those style the problem is still there..

Anybody know how to get rid of this white frame? I'm not good at all with CSS and this is so weird...I tried lots of tweaks, but none worked...

Thanks!
Alex

EDIT: As suggested, I've created a new class in my main css file:

```
.loading_panel{
border: none;
background: transparent;
}
```

Modified the ui.xml:

```
     <g:HTMLPanel>
        <div class="loading_container">
        <label class="loading_label">Loading info from itsaseus buoys</label>
        <div class="bubblingG">
            <span id="bubblingG_1">
            </span>
            <span id="bubblingG_2">
            </span>
            <span id="bubblingG_3">
            </span>
        </div>
        </div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

And I'm associating the style when I create the popup:

```
        m = new LoadingDialogMessage();
    m.addStyleName("loading_panel");
    m.show();
```

And this is the generated HTML code:

```
<div class="gwt-PopupPanel loading_panel" style="left: 649px; top: 444px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; overflow: visible;">
        <div class="popupContent"><div>
            <div class="loading_container"> 
                <label class="loading_label">Loading info from itsaseus buoys</label> 
                    <div class="bubblingG"> 
                        <span id="bubblingG_1"> </span> 
                        <span id="bubblingG_2"> </span> 
                        <span id="bubblingG_3"> </span> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

While the loading_panel style is added, GWT is adding the gwt-PopupPanel style and also this:

```
style="left: 649px; top: 444px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; overflow: visible;"
```

Looks like addStyleName is not overriding at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to override a css class like bellow.

```
.gwt-PopupPanel {
    border: none !important;
    background: none !important;
 }
```

Comment: Wow, I've just added this and it works! Looks like you definitely have to override the gwt-PopupPanel class, thank you Mayank!! Now I really don't know who to give the correct answer here :D

Answer (score 1):

You should add a css that is proper to the borderless popups. Then apply this css to all popups you want in that style. Avoid using !important in your css: you can do it only once. So keep it for special cases like *onMouseOver* or the *disabled* state

So to recapitulate:
 1. create a special popup style:

```
.borderlessPopup {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

- apply it to you popups:

  popup.addStyleName("borderlessPopup");

Comment: Hi, I've added that css class to my current css file and added the style when the popup is created but no effects...I can still see the white frame...looks the style is not applied to the parent g:HTMLPanel at all...

Comment: Hi, Did you check what is happening in firebug? (firefox plugin to see a page's html, css and js)
You should have a div for your PopupPanel popupPanel.
We use 
popupPanel.setStyleName("categoriesPopup"); which removes completely the default Popup style, you could try this to check from where the problem comes, but you should definitely go to your HTML result code and disgonize what is happening

Comment: Yes it will work, it's normal. But it's the brutal way to put !important in your css.

Comment: I removed the important! thingy and still works...is not that I think, is just that you need to overwrite the gwt-PopupPanel class yes or yes...

Comment: :-) Ok so you condamn all your popups not to have a border. Yes and enough, do it like you think

Comment: Yes, you can call it a side-effect, altough not mandatory if I remove the default style in gwt-PopupPanel and add the transparent background to a custom css style. In my case, overriding the gwt-PopupPanel is enough. Thanks for your help Zied!

Comment: You're welcome. I gave the recommended approach GWT was designed with. You'll always find alternative ways, but when you're in the alternative, you can have surprises :-)